# Configure OFF-HEAP for Apache Spark 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, alluxio

Please help me to understand following

1. What are the steps to configure OFF-HEAP storage for Apache Spark
   2.x ?
2. Is it possible to configure Alluxio as the OFF-HEAP storage in 2.0 ? Is it removed since 2.x ?
3. How does OFF-HEAP works with Dynamic Allocation, where executors being added and removed randomly on demand?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the steps to configure OFF-HEAP storage for Apache Spark 2.x ?

No additional steps are required.

> Is it possible to configure Alluxio as the OFF-HEAP storage in 2.0 ? Is it removed since 2.

It is not. External block store has been removed in Spark 2.0: [SPARK-12667 - Remove block manager's internal "external block store" API](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12667). You can use Alluxio as a normal file system instead.

> How does OFF-HEAP works with Dynamic Allocation, where executors being added and removed randomly on demand?

Because OFF-HEAP is internal, it will loose blocks as any other storage level.

Check:

- [Off-heap storage and dynamic allocation](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Off-heap-storage-and-dynamic-allocation-td14842.html)
- [SPARK-21097 Dynamic allocation will preserve cached data](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21097)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But I have few more doubts here , 1) who manages OFF-HEAP memory ? Is managed by individual Spark Executor ? 2) How does the OFF-HEAP memory allocation reflect to the Resource Managers like Mesos ? Do we need to do any static reservation in Mesos?